# C Programming help(computer guesses number user is thinking)

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strlib.h>
main()
{
    int n = 50;
    int m;
    char answer[100];

    printf("Think of a number in the range of 1-%d and I'll guess it.\n",n);
    m = n/2 ;

    while( m>1 )
    {   
        printf("Is the number %d?", m);
        scanf("%s",answer);


        if (strcmp(answer,"no")==0)
            {       
                //i = n/2;
                printf("Is the number less than %d?",m);
                scanf("%s",answer);

                if(strcmp(answer,"no")==0)
                    {   
                        m = m + (n - m)/2;
                    }

                else if(strcmp(answer,"yes")==0)
                        {
                            m = m/2;
                        }                                                       
            }
        else if(strcmp(answer,"yes")==0)
            {
                printf("I have have succeeded in guessing your number. %d\n",m);
                break;
            }
    }        
}
```

---

There seems to be some sort of issue in the "m = m/2;" code. I cannot figure out what it is though. Does anyone know what the issues are? I've tried multiple ways. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did any of the multiple ways involve using a debugger of printf to track the program flow and show variable contents at it goes?

Comment: Please tell us what incorrect behaviour or "issue" you are observing. Please tell us what you found during your debugging.

Comment: Please describe your "issues": what happens and what do you think should happen.

Comment: So the number I was thinking of was 39. Once I reached 43 I divided it by 2, which it ended in 21. But I had already showed the program that it was larger than 25. So I'm thinking the "m = m/2;" is wrong somewhere. Basically, the calculation m/2 isn't right. And I am not able to think of a better one.

Comment: What does it mean "I had already showed the program"? How did you do it?

Comment: Here this is how it looks like in the command prompt: https://ibb.co/jy40fa

Comment: "Basically, the calculation m/2 isn't right" You're dead right there. You need to keep track of the bounds you've closed off and `m/2` doesn't do that. Try keeping a `high` and a `low` value. When you know the secret is greater than the guess, can you guess what the new `low` is?

Comment: I would have to store multiple high and lows right?

Comment: Nope. Just the lowest high and the highest low. Work it through on paper and watch the two numbers converge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have written I can deduce that you are trying to partition the search space into half based on the yes or no response. The issue I see is that the lower bound of your search range does not change at all, your upper bound does, and the next search key (m) is not really a mid-point but something else (m = m + (n - m)/2) leading to the behavior you are running into

```
m = 25   [ number is > 25 ] [ search-range = (0,37) ]
m = 37   [ number is > 37 ] [ search-range = (0,43) ]
m = 21   [ number is < 21 ] [ search-range = (0,10) ]
..
```

At this point in the above example we know we have gone in the wrong direction!

The logic needs to adjust the lower-bound and upper-bound at each stage, thereby narrowing the range of search, and the search key is always the mid-point of that range. If the guessed number is less than the mid-point then the upper-bound changes to mid-point-1, if its greater than the mid-point, then the lower-bound changes to mid-point+1 or else its a match. (Also if lower bound ever becomes greater than upper bound then whatever you are searching for is not in the original range). Essentially this is a binary search.

Here is an example of how the search range is adjusted after each failed match for the example you took

```
25   [ number is > 25 ] [ change lower-bound search-range = (26,50) ]
38   [ number is > 38 ] [ change lower-bound search-range = (39,50) ]
44   [ number is < 44 ] [ change upper-bound search-range =  (39-43) ]
41   [ number is < 41 ] [ change upper-bound search-range =  (39-40) ]
39   <<< you have a match
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic error too. Answer 2, 1 (if your range of 1 to XX is inclusive of 1) is unable to print correct in your case.

```
50 / 2 = 25
25 / 2 = 13
13 / 2 = 6
6 / 2 = 3
3 / 2 = 1 ( condition of m > 1 will not be true and exit the loop )
```